# Angular - Render a component conditionally inside a child component basis a reference from the parent component

Tags: angular

Essentially I have a dropdown component wherein I want to render chips conditionally for selected options on the basis of reference passed in parent.

For e.g -
parent.component.html
`<app-select chips />`

Intended Use in dropdown.component.html

```
<section class="selected-option-container">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of selectedOptions; let last= last">
    <ng-container *ngIf ="!chips">
      <span class="selected-item">
        <span>{{option.text}}</span>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!last">,&nbsp;</ng-container>
      </span>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="chips">
      <app-chip>{{option.text}}</app-chip>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</section>
```

I have tried a few different things -

1. Using ViewChild with the selector 'chip' - it didn't work out since #chip in parent template was a local template reference and would not work within my usecase.
2. Using @Input chips: boolean = false in my dropdown file - I was expecting that passing chips directly in parent without specifying true will indicate to true. I don't want user to send in a value but essentially render chips on the existence of the 'prop' itself.